# Swagger-ui with multiple top-level definition files

Tags: microservices, swagger-ui, openapi

I know the same issue has been posted in the past, but I could not find a relevant recent answer. We have quite a lot of APIs, which are all exposed by the same domain name. Each API defines its own openapi file.

Hosting each openapi file for documentation purpose is straight forward, but we'd like to have swagger-ui (or any other tool) to host an aggregated version. We cannot easily do the agregation ourselves, as we may have objects names and security conflicts in the definitions files.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: Something like this? -- [Swagger UI with multiple URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44816594/113116)