# Service one page from multiple OpenAPI spec endpoints?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

We are running set of micro-services and each are exposing open-api spec to url like the following.

```
https://{domain}/v1/membership/v3/api-docs
https://{domain}/v1/storage/v3/api-docs
https://{domain}/v1/order/v3/api-docs
```

The url opens open-api json (not UI).

Does anyone know of a tool where I can combine these and be able serve all the apis via url like https://{domain}/v1/apis with UI?

I looked Google and all I saw required me to create a single json file with all apis instead of dynamically serving these.

Comment: Instead of merging the OpenAPI files, you can have a [single Swagger UI page for multiple APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44819386/113116). This configuration exists in standalone Swagger UI, not sure about springdoc-openapi-ui configs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property `urls`:

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[0].name = first
springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[0].url = /firstAPI.yaml

springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[1].name = second
springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[1].url = /secondAPI.yaml
```

You can find this property in the [documentation](https://springdoc.org/springdoc-properties.html#swagger-ui-properties). There is also a nice [FAQ](https://springdoc.org/faq.html#how-can-i-agreagte-external-endpoints-exposing-openapi-3-spec-inside-one-single-application) for this question:

> The properties springdoc.swagger-ui.urls.*, are suitable to configure external (/v3/api-docs url). For example if you want to agreagte all the endpoints of other services, inside one single application. Don’t forget that CORS needs to be enabled as well.