# OpenAPI, Swagger-UI - Dropdown for [Explore]

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

I have this working across multiple apps -

https://lornajane.net/posts/2020/creating-a-simple-openapi-spec

I want the ability to quickly switch across the apps instead having to retype.

How can I make the [Explore] a dropdown?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swagger UI with multiple URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44816594/113116)

Comment: Yes, that has answered my question. Thanks very much! I appreciate.