Change URL Search Bar L5-Swagger Laravel
The Swagger UI for L5 Swagger in Laravel by default shows a URL search bar:

But I want it to show a select definition dropdown that let's me select the version (v1,v2,v3,etc.) (I took this picture from a C# API):

How do I code or change the configuration for this?? I've done Laravel for a while now, but just recently started analising using Swagger

In standalone Swagger UI, this is done by using the urls config as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44819386/113116. Check if L5-Swagger has a similar config.

If you run php artisan vendor:publish and select the L5SwaggerServiceProvider , then you should end up with a view that you can edit following the instructions in the answer linked in Helen's comment
